# FuelPHP model's / fieldset / form

Tags: php, fuelphp, fuelphp-orm

I am new developing fuelPHP and I have 4 questions about it:

1. I am building a form which uses 2 models, I do this:

   ```
   $fieldset = Fieldset::forge('register_form');
   $fieldset->add_model('Model_Ntk_User');
   $fieldset->add_model('Model_Ntk_Users_Social_Network');
   ```

   But some fields has same name, how can I solve that?. I found a method set_form_fields, but not much info about it.
2. In Yii, in example you can build a model using CActiveRecord (if linked to a table) or CFormModel to build Contact forms in example, how this is done with fuelPHP, model_crud?
3. If I use html form (not build using fieldset) how can I use validation without adding the validation rules in the controller, since they are already set on $_properties in the model?
4. I have created an Observer which adds values to fields like ip_added and date_added, but first is triggered the Observers: Typing and Validation, since those fields are set to "not null" Typing observer throw an exception. So far I have fix it making those fields "null" but I think that is bad idea.

Comment: can you elaborate on what you did so far?

Comment: Actually it would be better to ask four separate questions. It is easier to answer.

Comment: And also easier to vote on them separately. Your questions seem good questions, btw, so they're worth asking.
(You should probably edit this question to keep the one closest to the permalink, and ask only the remaining questions separately, but probably you knew that.)

Comment: I will add them as separate questions, thanks !